# Do singular $G_2$-holonomy manifolds in M-theory have stable compactifications?

Tags: string-theory, compactification, kaluza-klein, calabi-yau, moduli

In this paper: [Chiral Fermions from Manifolds of G2 Holonomy](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0109152) it is shown that compactifications of M-theory on a $7d$ $G_2$-holonomy manifold $X$, generate chiral fermions, if only $X$ is singular.

I want to know if there exists any compactification on such **singular** $G_2$-holonomy manifold that gives rise to **stable** extra compact dimensions.

In other words:

**Is there any problem that the singularity can pose for the moduli stabilisation?**

Comment: What does "stable" mean here? Stable *under what dynamics*? Also, the $G_2$-manifolds here *are* the compactification manifold, so don't they *all* "give rise to extra compact dimensions"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind The emphesis is on stability of, and not the existence of the new dimensions. I thought M-theory should introduce naturally its own dynamics for moduli stabilisation. There's no assumption for the stability of such extra dimensions under quantum fluctuations in the paper.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.20559 is a recent review on moduli stabilization with a short section on M theory (section 5.4)

Comment: @MitchellPorter Thanks but as it is aluuded by the paper: "Overall, despite much study of the geometry and physics of manifolds of G2 holonomy (see e.g. [280–285] and references therein), the details of moduli stabilization are not yet as fully developed, especially in the more realistic setups with singularities, as in the string theory case". The question is particularly concerned with the singular such manifolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only serious study I'm aware of, of moduli stabilization on such manifolds, is [this 2007 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0701034), part of a series of papers developing the "G2-MSSM", a paradigm for obtaining the MSSM from such compactifications, that was supposed to have distinctive phenomenological implications (e.g. that MSSM parameters fall within highly specific ranges). I have not had time to go over the line of argument. A [2022 thesis](https://lsa.umich.edu/content/dam/math-assets/math-document/Grad/defenses/Nguyen,%20Khoa%20-%20Thesis.pdf) has a page on the topic (Section V.9).

Comment: I admire the time you spent to find the thesis which has the most relevant stuff I've seen to this moment, but since there's not much time left and the bounty expires soon, I give you the bounty, but I hope you answer further questions when I study the case more closely.